# How to get the rootdir parameter value while executing pytest

Tags: python, pytest

After executing the pytest I could see its populating the rootdir in results based on the path of "pytest.ini". My issue is I need to use relative path to read some of the files as part of testing, so is there a way to fetch this "rootdir" parameter value during test execution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`request`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#request) fixture. Example:

```
def test_ini(request):
    rootdir = request.config.rootdir
    assert (rootdir / 'pytest.ini').isfile()
```